# Azure Bastion Service - Any reason why the connection between the Azure portal and the bastion subnet is over the internet? `

Tags: azure, service, ip, public

Any reason why the connection between the Azure portal and the bastion subnet is over the internet? I guess that's why you need a public IP for the bastion service but ideally it would be a service endpoint over the Azure backbone. In the image below you see that SSL traffic is going over the Internet from the portal to the Bastion Service subnet, ideally this would be using a private IP and over the Microsoft backbone and not the internet. Perhaps there is a way to mimic this behavior with a VPN or some sort of gateway. Thanks for any answers.
[image]

Comment: well the Azure Portal itself is obviously hosted on a public endpoint only. So I'm not sure what you exact question is, i.e. how else you would see this being built?

Comment: Agreed, the portal is on a public endpoint. My question is right after that endpoint is reached, why traffic is not routed through the Microsoft backbone to the bastion private ip instead of using the internet. So in the diagram, it would be the second hop coming from the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there are two misconceptions here:

- All traffic between Azure resources, even when they go over public endpoints (IPs), do indeed stay on the Microsoft network/backbone. But, since they are public endpoints, this is still defined as "Internet" - even though it is not routed somewhere else in between
- For Bastion in specific: Once you start a Bastion connection from the Azure Portal in your Browser, usually a new window/tab opens with a new address, which is not portal.azure.com. So your client directly connects there over the internet, not through the Azure portal.

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot.If the connection from the portal to the bastion service is done via the Microsoft backbone then that would suffice to calm down our security team.